# Index text data for search in C#

Tags: c#, search, indexing

I have database table like *[**Id** = 1, **Title** = "some text here..."]*. This db exists on two different hosting environments. I need to implement single endpoint for search in both tables. This endpoint will be used for autocomplete on UI. My thoughts here:

1. in 1st request after start of application: get data from both hosting environments, join, cache (it's possible to apply some kind of warmup in *Application_Start*)
2. I need to index this data to make search faster, not like this:

   ```
   foreach(string searchItem in searchtext.Split(' '))
   {
       foreach(Item item in listOfAllitems)
       {
           foreach(string titleItem in item.Title.Split(' '))
           {
               //check for startswith or contains here
           }
       }
   }
   ```

   And of course final sorting is required. My thoughts about search:
3. split all titles using whitespace and build sorted array like this:

   ```
   {ambitious, [hashset of items where Title starts with 'ambitious']},
   {bad, [hashset of items where Title starts with 'bad']}
   ...
   ```
4. make binary search for each word from search text -> result is list of hashsets for each word
5. find intersection between hashsets, sort the result

Am I reinventing a wheel? Do you know good algorithms for this purpose?
**UPDATE**: the number of records in both databases is ~30.000.

Comment: I have no idea what your data set size is or which RDBMS you are using but much of this can **probably** be done database side. Sql Server for example has [Full Text Search](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx).

Comment: @Igor I thought about it. I Added info about size. I need to make requests to both databases and I can interact with db from another hosting center only using api (it's not available directly). So having single list in cache looks good here.

Comment: Your data set is relatively small.  I think you can simply keep them as strings (do not split) and execute a regex to find matches.

Comment: Here's a pretty sophisticated + efficient string search algo: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree

Comment: In the past I've used Lucene with Ms/MySQL https://lucenenet.apache.org/ and I didn't get any performance complaints just some minor glitches due to wrong indexing.